# NodeJS fetch is not returning all of JSON data, but on browser going to the api link everything shows up?

Tags: node.js, api, axios

Was initially thinking it was an issue with my API key, but now I am not so sure as whenever I go to my `localhost:3001/api/route` the JSON returned on the page has everything included and the fetch worked perfectly

However inside of node, I am using `axios` fetch inside an async route function, so I am using

```
const results = await axios.get('url')
console.log(results.data)
```

but whenever I print the results inside of NodeJS, some of the items return correctly but a lot of the object attributes are just [Array] or [Object] and are not showing me the actual inner contents. Even though again on the browser, everything works fine.

Whats strange is that the await should be waiting for the entire successful fetch, so I am not sure that is the issue.

Any help?

Comment: try 
res.send(results.data.json)

Comment: Just try to output the response like this `console.log(JSON.stringify(results.data, null, 2))`